# validate email field and make sure not blank

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am running a little jQuery script on a form field when the form is attempted to be submitted to check the email form field is completed correctly as I cant rely on the HTML5 validation. Code is as below... issue is... if you leave the field blank and hit the submit button it validates as correct when it should be false.. what am I missing?

```
<script>

function validateEmail(email) {
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
return emailReg.test( email );
}

var clicked = jQuery(".button");

clicked.click(function() {
var email = jQuery("input[type='email']").val();
( !validateEmail(email) ) ? alert('Please complete the mandatory email field') : this.form.action='https://brandname.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=123&amp;id=abc';this.form.submit();
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression doesnt check if email is empty , so add the check to the if like this :

```
 (email && !validateEmail(email) ) ? alert('Please complete the mandatory email field'):
```

Comment: thanks - still allows blank field to be recognised as valid though?